# I don't understand why there isn't any save or append data operation at the last stage

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

```
      df.writeStream
      .foreachBatch((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
        batchDF.write
          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
          .cassandraFormat(cassandraTable, cassandraKeyspace, cassandraCluster)
          .mode("append")
          .save())
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

At the end of the code, dataframe is written to cassandra table.

After checking the last stage through the UI, there was no part to execute save/append-data.

[image]

I wonder why it doesn't exist or is there something I've missed.

=========================== After changing my code ===========================

```
      .writeStream
//      .foreachBatch((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
//        batchDF.write
//          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
//          .cassandraFormat(cassandraTable, cassandraKeyspace, cassandraCluster)
//          .mode("append")
//          .save())
      .cassandraFormat(cassandraTable, cassandraKeyspace, cassandraCluster)
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

[image]

But I can see WriteToDataSourceV2 in SQL tab.

[image]

Comment: what version of Spark & SCC are you using?

Comment: Spark 3.0 and SCC 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it’s not directly answering your question, but for Spark 3.0 and SCC 3.0.0 (you should use 3.0.0-beta) you shouldn’t use foreachBatch, but just write data as-is by specifying Cassandra format - since SCC 2.5.0 Spark Structured Streaming is natively supported - see announcement: https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all

Comment: Wow! That's what I needed. I really appreciate your help. I don't know about the Native Support for Spark Structured Streaming.

Comment: Yes, that is recent release, but now all commercial features are open source (and even more)

Comment: After changing my code, I still got the issue. I think there needs something to fix! 
Maybe I post about this issue on Github. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you post the error? Because here is the working code: https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/scc-2.5/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingKafkaDSE.scala (tested with Spark 2.4 + SCC 2.5.0 although)